# How to use a variable declared in VBA in an excel sheet

Tags: excel, vba

As a simple example if i have the a sheet with cell

```
A1= AUM
```

And i have the following sub:

```
Public Sub MainValuesInForm()
    Dim Wanted_Data As String
    
    Wanted_Data = "AUM"
    ActiveCell.Formula = "=IF(""Wanted_Data""=A1,1,2)"
        
End Sub
```

In this case, Wanted_Data does equal A1 so it should return 1.
However, the formula that is inserted into the activecell is always

```
=IF("Wanted_Data"=A1,1,2)
```

How can i get the desired behavior such that in this case it becomes:

```
=IF("AUM"=A1,1,2)
```

Comment: `ActiveCell.Formula =  "=IF(""" & Wanted_Data & """=A1,1,2)"`  ?

Comment: Question/answers suggested by @GSerg do not cover off the issue OP is having as the issue is regarding correct structure of quotation marks in a formula.

Comment: @CLR Ok, I've added more.